# Java Spring Framework+Quartz Clustering For N-Different Node on Network

Tags: java, spring, oracle, quartz-scheduler

I am getting following excetion - org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist  [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ].

I already worked with same code but database was **Mysql**, But suddenly we have been decided to migrate database to ORACLE.

And we get up above Exception from java side.

As per my opinion, I think when initially job runs, 
it will enter following entries to the database table : PREFIX_LOCKS

STATE_ACCESS
TRIGGER_ACCESS

Automatically, But here it tries but failure because of ORA-00942.

Now, My Quartz Config file looks like,

```
#=====================================
# Configure Instance
#=====================================

    org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyClusteredScheduler

    org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO

#===================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#===================================

    org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool

    org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25

    org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5


#===================================
# Configure JobStore
#===================================

    org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

    org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX

    org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate

    org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false

    org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = TABLE_PREFIX_NAME

    org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = customDataSourceName

    org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true

    org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000

#===================================
# Configure Datasources  
#====================================

    org.quartz.dataSource.customDataSourceName.jndiURL =
    java:comp/env/jdbc/SomeName

    org.quartz.dataSource.customDataSourceName.maxConnections = 5

    org.quartz.dataSource.customDataSourceName.validationQuery = 
    select 0 from dual

#================== END OF FILE ==========
```

**NOTE :** My Oracle Database has all sufficient tables which are required by quartz & into oracle database is distributed into Schema wise(May be this is cause).

Can anybody tell me whats went wrog ?

Comment: Also Note that, I am using quartz-2.2.1.jar

Comment: Finally, I got solution.
Issue was, from ORACLE database i haven't sufficient privileges to access that tables.

Comment: This Problem has been resolved Successfully with Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Problem resolved.

Problem was,
I was trying to invoke start() method of Scheduler before schedule(..) method.
.
I just swap that order and make that likewise,

```
1. schedule job
2. start method invoke
```

above both situation enclosed inside try.. catch...

Thank you.