# Configure clustering with more than one node in Quartz scheduler?

Tags: java, maven, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz scheduler (2.2.1) with MySql as JobStore in a maven based application and I want to implement the clustering feature of Quartz. There are no http calls involved in the task. Hence, I am directly running the jar that are built using fatJar.

I have added the quartz.properties file in the classpath.

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
#============================================================================
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyClusteredScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = HOST1
#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#============================================================================
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources
#============================================================================
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = user
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = password
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery=select 0 from dual

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore
#============================================================================
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
```

InstanceId is different for 2 nodes. Rest everything is same. But when I run the two jars as a cluster, my job is getting executed twice (once by each jar).

My build.gradle looks like this.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

version = '1.0'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

//create a single Jar with all dependencies


task fatJar(type: Jar) {

    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                'Main-Class': 'com.xxx.xxxxx.Application'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

//Get dependencies from Maven central repository
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
    compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:4.0.0.GA"
    compile "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.4"
    compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.35"
    compile "org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1"
    compile "org.quartz-scheduler:quartz-jobs:2.2.1"
    compile "org.quartz-scheduler:quartz-commonj:2.1.7"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.19"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.19"
    compile "org.jdbi:jdbi:2.63.1"
    compile "org.antlr:stringtemplate:3.2"
    compile "redis.clients:jedis:2.6.3"
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3"
    compile "com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:3.5.6"
    compile "org.json:json:20150729"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.6.3"
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.3"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-email:1.4"

}
```

Is it not possible to have cluster while running the jar directly (java -jar /path/to/jar.jar)? Or am I missing something?

One of the suspect was that my build.gradle did not include quartz-all, quartz-commonj, slf4j jar references (as per http://www.tutorialsavvy.com/2012/12/quartz-scheduler-scheduling-job-in-java.html/). So I added all these references except quartz-all. I cannot find the appropriate jar in maven repository. All jars present in maven are from opensymphony and they don't work with the other quartz related jars that I am using.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please refer this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666351/java-spring-frameworkquartz-clustering-for-n-different-node-on-network

Comment: In my case, the jobs are running without exceptions. The problem is all my nodes are working independent of each other. They are not running as a cluster. Checked DB permissions. All looks good there

Comment: take care that same code runs from different machine, means you need to deploy same things on different machine(server) which are belongs under same network

Comment: @Tejeshwar, did you find any solution to this..can any one help me in this, trying to achieve the clustering through java. Problem is, all my schedulers are running together the same job.